# Java Layout Frustration

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I need guidance with GUI Layouts

To narrow it down to main points:

- I have three main JPanels (info section, operations and data
  structure)
- I cannot populate these without the JLabels being shifted
- I need a sub-panel for operations with a grid layout (cannot get this
  to work and it's really annoying me now)
- I need it to look like the picture below
- Red separator lines are optional to make it a bit more neater

My next step is to implement a stack but I want to first make it look normal.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7G2g.jpg]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class StackPanel extends JPanel {

    JPanel west, westSub1, east, south, southSub1;
    JTextArea infoText, popText, pushText, peekText, resultText;
    JLabel aTitle, bTitle, cTitle, Result;
    JButton push, pop, peek, test;

    public StackPanel() {        

        // Creating JPanels
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        west = new JPanel();
        westSub1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,2));
        east = new JPanel();
        south = new JPanel();
        west.add(westSub1);

        // Creating JLabels / JTextArea
        aTitle = new JLabel("Operations");
        bTitle = new JLabel("Data Structure Contents");
        cTitle = new JLabel("Information");
        infoText = new JTextArea("This is where commands will be displayed.");
        pushText = new JTextArea("pushtxt");
        popText = new JTextArea("poptxt");
        peekText = new JTextArea("g");
        resultText = new JTextArea("");
        west.add(aTitle);
        westSub1.add(pushText);
        westSub1.add(popText);
        westSub1.add(peekText);
        westSub1.add(resultText);
        east.add(bTitle);
        south.add(cTitle);
        south.add(infoText);

        // Creating & Adding JButtons
        push = new JButton("PUSH");
        pop = new JButton("POP") ;
        peek = new JButton("PEEK");
        test = new JButton("TEST");
        westSub1.add(push);
        westSub1.add(pop);
        westSub1.add(peek);
        westSub1.add(test);

        // Setting the placements of GUI objects
        add(west, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(east, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(south, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        // Declaring JPanel sizes // Width|Height
        west.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
        east.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,100));
        south.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,150));

        // Setting black borders for JPanels
        west.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        east.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        south.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

        // Setting JPanel background colours
        west.setBackground(new Color(234,237,242));
        east.setBackground(new Color(255,255,255));
        south.setBackground(new Color(240,240,240));
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. How about an additional small effort to make your code [MCVE] ?

Comment: @AndrewThompson It's educational sadly so I cannot just sack it off..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something to get you started. Please read comments. I did not do all needed layout changes: I did just about to demonstrate what should be done, so you get the idea.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class StackPanel extends JPanel {

    JPanel west, westSub1, east, south, southSub1;
    JTextArea infoText, popText, pushText, peekText, resultText;
    JLabel aTitle, bTitle, cTitle, Result;
    JButton push, pop, peek, test;

    public StackPanel() {

        // Creating JPanels
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    
        // Creating JLabels / JTextArea
        aTitle = new JLabel("Operations");
        bTitle = new JLabel("Data Structure Contents");

        west = new JPanel();
        //you need to set layout manager to the panel, to lay out its components
        west.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        west.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
        west.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        west.setBackground(new Color(234,237,242));
        add(west, BorderLayout.WEST);

        west.add(aTitle, BorderLayout.NORTH);//use panel's layout manager

        //you have 4 rows so GridLayout(3,2) is wrong
        westSub1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,2));

        //for a grid layout: add components in the right order
        push = new JButton("PUSH");
        westSub1.add(push);

        pushText = new JTextArea("pushtxt");
        westSub1.add(pushText);

        pop = new JButton("POP") ;
        westSub1.add(pop);

        popText = new JTextArea("poptxt");
        westSub1.add(popText);

        peek = new JButton("PEEK");
        westSub1.add(peek);

        peekText = new JTextArea("g");
        westSub1.add(peekText);

        test = new JButton("TEST");
        westSub1.add(test);

        resultText = new JTextArea("");
        westSub1.add(resultText);

        west.add(westSub1, BorderLayout.CENTER);//use panel's layout manager

        east = new JPanel();
        east.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,100));
        east.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        east.setBackground(new Color(255,255,255));

        east.add(bTitle);
        add(east, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        south = new JPanel();
        //you need to set layout manager to the panel, to lay out its components
        south.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        south.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,150));
        south.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        south.setBackground(new Color(240,240,240));
        add(south, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        cTitle = new JLabel("Information");
        south.add(cTitle, BorderLayout.NORTH); //use panel's layout manager
        infoText = new JTextArea("This is where commands will be displayed.");
        south.add(infoText, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

          JFrame frame = new JFrame();
          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

          frame.getContentPane().add(new StackPanel());
          frame.pack();
          frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The code has all the imports it needs, as wall as a `main` to run it.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe instead of using labels at the top of each of the west/east/south panels you can use a `TitledBorder`. This will put a rectangular line around the panel with a title at the top.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for more information and working examples.

If you don't want to do this then you will probably need to change the default FlowLayout or each of the panels to another layout. For example you could use a `BorderLayout`. Then add the label to the `PAGE_START` and the other components to the `CENTER`. The main point is you can nest panels with different layout to achieve your desired layout.

Answer (score 0):

It's a long time ago that I worked with Swing. But I had the same troubles with the default layouts of Swing. My tip is to change to the TableLayout. It's really easy to use and you can get exact results.

Please check the tutorial: http://www.clearthought.info/sun/products/jfc/tsc/articles/tablelayout/Simple.html

Not perfect but I would chance your code like this

```
public class StackPanel extends JPanel {

JPanel west, east, south, southSub1;
JTextArea infoText, popText, pushText, peekText, resultText;
JLabel aTitle, bTitle, cTitle, Result;
JButton push, pop, peek, test;

public StackPanel() {

    // Creating JPanels
    double size[][] =  {{0.3, 0.7}, {TableLayout.FILL, 70}};
    setLayout(new TableLayout(size));

    double sizeWest[][] =  {{0.5, 0.5}, {20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20}};
    setLayout(new TableLayout(size));

    west = new JPanel(new TableLayout(sizeWest));


    east = new JPanel();
    south = new JPanel();


    // Creating JLabels / JTextArea
    aTitle = new JLabel("Operations");
    bTitle = new JLabel("Data Structure Contents");
    cTitle = new JLabel("Information");
    infoText = new JTextArea("This is where commands will be displayed.");
    pushText = new JTextArea("pushtxt");
    popText = new JTextArea("poptxt");
    peekText = new JTextArea("g");
    resultText = new JTextArea("");
    west.add(aTitle, "0,0,1,0");
    west.add(pushText, "0,1");
    west.add(popText, "0,2");
    west.add(peekText, "0,3");
    west.add(resultText, "0,4");
    east.add(bTitle);
    south.add(cTitle);
    south.add(infoText);

    // Creating & Adding JButtons
    push = new JButton("PUSH");
    pop = new JButton("POP") ;
    peek = new JButton("PEEK");
    test = new JButton("TEST");
    west.add(push, "1,1");
    west.add(pop,"1,2");
    west.add(peek,"1,3");
    west.add(test, "1,4");

    // Setting the placements of GUI objects
    add(west, "0,0");
    add(east, "1,0");
    add(south, "0,1, 1,1");

    // Declaring JPanel sizes // Width|Height
    west.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
    east.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,100));
    south.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,150));

    // Setting black borders for JPanels
    west.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    east.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    south.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

    // Setting JPanel background colours
    west.setBackground(new Color(234,237,242));
    east.setBackground(new Color(255,255,255));
    south.setBackground(new Color(240,240,240));
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic Swing layout managers are either very rudimentary or very complicated to use.
Therefore maybe [FormLayout](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/libraries/forms/) or [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) may be an option to use, which are sophisticated, but not too complicated to use.